# Django/Nginx - Error 403 Forbidden when serving media files over some size

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-media

When user uploads image, it is stored in `media` folder inside project directory. The problem is that when they want to see it on the website, nginx return `403 Forbidden` error for images over approximately 3 Mb.

I set `nginx.conf` `client_max_body_size` to 8M

```
http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        client_max_body_size 8M;
     ...
```

And already changed memory size in `settings.py`:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 8388608
```

When I upload an image under 3 MB, there are no problems, if I upload image over 3 MB, I can see it inside `media` folder but the error is raised instead of serving image:

```
GET https://example.com/media/images/dom.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

I noticed that files under 3 MB have different permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 django www-data    4962 Jul 19 19:51 61682_3995232_IMG_01_0000.jpg.150x84_q85_crop.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 django www-data 1358541 Jul 20 09:32 byt.jpg
-rw------- 1 django www-data 3352841 Jul 20 09:32 dom.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 django www-data    5478 Jul 19 20:10 downloasd.jpeg.150x84_q85_crop.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 django www-data    3225 Jul  9 22:53 images.jpeg.100x56_q85_crop.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 django www-data    6132 Jul 19 20:00 NorthYorkHouse2.JPG.150x84_q85_crop.jpg
```

Do you know where is the problem?

**EDIT:**

**VIEW**

```
class NehnutelnostUploadImagesView(LoginRequiredMixin, ExclusiveMaklerDetailView, DetailView):
    template_name = "nehnutelnosti/nehnutelnost_image_upload.html"
    model = Nehnutelnost

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = ImageUploadForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, nehnutelnost=self.object)
        if form.is_valid():
            nehnutelnost_image = form.save()
            images_count = self.object.images.count()

            data = {'is_valid': True, 'row_html': image_row_renderer(nehnutelnost_image, self.request),
                    'name': nehnutelnost_image.image.name, 'url': nehnutelnost_image.image.url,}
        else:
            images_count = self.object.images.count()

            data = {'is_valid': False, 'errors': form.errors, 'images_count': images_count}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NehnutelnostUploadImagesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['images'] = self.object.images.all()
        context['podorys'] = self.object.podorys
        return context
```

We use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload plugin to upload images.

```
$(function () {

            $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
                $("#fileupload").click();
            });

            $("#fileupload").fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                sequentialUploads: true, /* 1. SEND THE FILES ONE BY ONE */
                start: function (e) {  /* 2. WHEN THE UPLOADING PROCESS STARTS, SHOW THE MODAL */
                    $(".modal").modal().show();
                },
                stop: function (e) {  /* 3. WHEN THE UPLOADING PROCESS FINALIZE, HIDE THE MODAL */
                    $(".modal").modal().hide();
                    $(".modal-backdrop").hide();

                },
                {#                TODO Chrome bug?#}
                progressall: function (e, data) {  /* 4. UPDATE THE PROGRESS BAR */
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    var strProgress = progress + "%";
                    $(".progress-bar").css({"width": strProgress});
                    $(".progress-bar").text(strProgress);
                },
                done: function (e, data) {
                    if (data.result.is_valid) {

                        $(".gridly").prepend(
                            data.result.row_html
                        )


                    }
                    var message = data.result.message;
                    addMessage('success', message);
                    var errors = data.result.errors;
                    if (errors) {
                        $.each(errors, function (fieldname, error_messages) {
                            $.each(error_messages, function (_, message) {
                                addMessage('danger', message);
                            })
                        })
                    }
                    var images_count_span = $('#images_count');
                    var images_count = data.result.images_count;
                    images_count_span.text(' - ' + images_count);
                    makegrid();

                }

            });
```

Comment: What's the code you use to save the file?

Comment: @spectras I've added the code to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/):

> By default, if an uploaded file is smaller than 2.5 megabytes, Django will hold the entire contents of the upload in memory.

In more concrete terms, it means smaller files use the [MemoryFileUploadHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler) while larger files use the [TemporaryFileUploadHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler). The latter uses `tempfile` to create a temporary file with user-only access.

After going through all form and model validation and everything, the actual saving is performed by `FileSystemStorage._save` method. At this point, the file is still either a `TemporaryUploadedFile` or a `InMemoryUploadedFile` depending on its size.

Now, a TemporaryUploadedFile is an actual file, created by `tempfile`, with user-only permissions.

The save method does the smart thing: if given a temporary file (namely, `if hasattr(content, 'temporary_file_path')`), it moves it instead of copying it. This means it keeps its user-only permissions and remains unreadable by `www-data`.

The problem doesn't show up with InMemoryUploadedFile, which will simply use whatever default permissions the process has (in your case, read/write for both user and group).

**How to fix?**

The storage object can set the permissions if so requested. For the default storage object, you can set this using [`FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions). Here,

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS=0o640
```

…should do the trick.

(that's R/W for django user and read-only for nginx)

Comment: I've the same problem but I'm newbie with Django. I don't have understood where I must put "FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS=0o640". I put this in settings.py(if yes where?) or into the model of my upload app? @Milano

Comment: @MassimilianoMoraca As you can see spectras added a link to the source. If you click on the link FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS, you can see it should be in settings.py.

Comment: Thank you @Milano , I've see this but my dubt is where in settings.py I must put it....

Comment: I've put the code after STATICFILES_DIRS, at the end of settings.py, and nothing is change. Is too hard explane in wich part of that file is correct to put the code? Between MIDDLEWARE and ROOT_URLCONF, for example??

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put it (unless you overwrite it somewhere above). The problem is somewhere else. If it is production server, you should check your server limits, for example NGINX and Gunicorn.

Comment: Unfortunately, even this didn't solve my problem. Files greater than 3MB are still having different permissions resulting in denial of permission for nginx. `-rw-r-----` this is the permission set on the files which cannot be read. Other non problematic files have the permissions set as `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: @MohammedShareefC that's because your webserver is not in the same group as your django application, therefore it uses the "other" permission and not the "group" permission. You should probably fix that, but if you really cannot, then opening the files to reading to all users with `0o644` will work.

Comment: @spectras My nginx user is `www-data`. it worked well when `FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS=0o2755` was added