# django media images forbidden

Tags: django, nginx, media, http-status-code-403

I got a weird bug: after deploying my django project to server, particular directly in `media` is 403 forbidden for no reason, while others directories work fine and are properly loaded.

Everything works fine on local machine, but when it goes to the server, `avatar` directory is somehow forbidden, here's a tree diagram of my media folder.

```
.
├── [drwx------ 2.6K]  avatar
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 6.4K]  1.png
│   ├── [-rw-r--r--  16K]  48.png
│   ├── [-rw-r--r--  16K]  69.png
│   └── [-rw-r--r--  13K]  9.png
├── [drwxr-xr-x  192]  cdn
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x  384]  css
│   │   ├── [-rw-r--r--   27]  console.css
│   │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 8.2K]  demo.css
│   │   ├── [-rw-r--r--  58K]  fontawesome-5.14.0.all.min.css
│   │   └── [-rw-r--r--  215]  shelf.css
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x  224]  js
│   │   ├── [-rw-r--r--  59K]  demo.js
│   │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 5.3K]  embed.js
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x  256]  webfonts
│       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 131K]  fa-brands-400.ttf
│       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 199K]  fa-solid-900.ttf
├── [drwxr-xr-x  192]  common
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 230K]  bg.jpg
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- 152K]  bg2.jpg
├── [drwxr-xr-x   96]  demo
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- 3.5M]  Screen_Shot_2021-08-16_at_3.45.01_pm.png
├── [drwxr-xr-x  224]  look
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 111K]  main.jpg
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- 232K]  me.jpg
├── [drwxr-xr-x  160]  portray
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 3.5M]  Screen_Shot_2021-08-16_at_3.45.01_pm.png
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 3.5M]  Screen_Shot_2021-08-16_at_3.45.01_pm_VsswTUf.png
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- 3.5M]  Screen_Shot_2021-08-16_at_3.45.01_pm_XIA2JgY.png
├── [drwxr-xr-x  224]  profile
│   ├── [-rw-r--r--  14K]  IMG_1684.JPG
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 1.1K]  deleted.webp
├── [drwxr-xr-x  128]  projects
│   └── [-rw-r--r--  19K]  default.jpg
├── [drwxr-xr-x   96]  team
│   └── [-rw-r--r--  11K]  default.jpg
└── [drwxr-xr-x  288]  thumbnail
    ├── [-rw-r--r-- 184K]  seagull.png
    └── [-rw-r--r-- 341K]  typescript-in-react.png
```

all the resources I can load properly in my website except for `avatar` directory. that means I cannot load a single image. basically `avatar` contains 80 png images with numeric filename those are avatar frames for user to select their own.

I have tried

[Django/Nginx - Error 403 Forbidden when serving media files over some size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439689/django-nginx-error-403-forbidden-when-serving-media-files-over-some-size)

but did not work.

I found that most of images in `avatar` that is smaller than 16kb, which are a lot smaller that for example another image `portray.png` which is 3.5mb that can be properly served!

also I thought about png format, but pngs in other folder turns out loading perfectly!

when I load my page, in console it shows:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (1.png, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (60.png, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (11.png, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (79.png, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (25.png, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (31.png, line 0)
...
```

---

I also tried to upload an image (filename not in number but alphabets) that can be properly loaded and dumps it into `avatar` folder. tries load it from server, and it failed. seems everything in `avatar` is forbidden.

After tons of research I still have no clue and wonder why this happens. If any has been in this situation before please give me a hand.

I will be more than glad of any suggestions on possible reasons.

Comment: Your permissions on the `avatar` _directory_ are different from the other directories. See [Accessing files in a directory without x-permission?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission)

Comment: thanks very much for the two comments, very helpful and solved with `chmod o+x avatar`